# C# Getting error when pulling data from another Form (Winform - Access list from another from)

Tags: c#, winforms

hope all is fine with you all. I'm very lost on the following exercise;

I'm doing a very simple system, that there is a main List, that I hope I did correct as a class.
And this class will be populated and used by two different forms.

I think I was able to make it correct, but when it comes to calling the List on the Secondary form, but I'm having the error: MainPage.UserList is inaccessible due its protection level. - But all is public.

I've tried following this question: [How to access list from another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441019/how-to-access-list-from-another-form)
But couldn't match to the simple form I'm Working on.

Class List and the Reference Clas:

```
using System;

namespace UniversalList
{
    class User
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace UniversalList
{
    class ListDataBase : User
    {
        List<User> infoList = new List<User>();

        public ListDataBase(string name, string number)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Number = number;
        }

        public ListDataBase getList()
        {
            ListDataBase newList = new ListDataBase("test", "test");
            return newList;
        }
    }
}
```

Main form to populate the list

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UniversalList
{
    public partial class MainPage : Form
    {
        List<ListDataBase> userList = new List<ListDataBase>();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListDataBase user = new ListDataBase(txtBoxName.Text, txtBoxNumber.Text);
            userList.Add(user);
            dtGridViewList.DataSource = null;
            dtGridViewList.DataSource = userList;
        }

        private void btnOtherForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LowerPage lower = new LowerPage();
            lower.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the form which I get the error:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UniversalList
{
    public partial class LowerPage : Form
    {
        public LowerPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dtGridViewList.DataSource = null;
            dtGridViewList.DataSource = MainPage.userList;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks and a good one,

Comment: To use the syntax `MainPage.userList`, the `userList` variable would have to be both `public` and `static`.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I will try this out. - At the MainPage correct? as: Static Public List<ListDataBase> userList = new List<ListDataBase>();